# jQuery - putting the attribute of a clicked HTML-Element into a src of an image

Tags: html, jquery, dom, events, attributes

i have a HTML site with some pictures with links attached to them.
When one the pictures/links is clicked, i want that the picture opens up on the same page without following the link. I also want the rest of the page to be overlayed by a black .

My idea is to add a  and an  with the src of the cliked link to the HTML-body.

But when i try to get the src-attribute it is always "undefined".
Can someone explain me how to fix it.

I did some research and found out, that i'm probabaly using the "this" keyword in a wrong way, but i don't really understand why.
Since i'm a beginner with Javascript and jQuery, i don't really know how to transfer it to my problem.

**HTML**

```
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="gallery">
      <a href="palette1.png"><img src="palette1.png" alt="" class="gallery-item"></a>
      <a href="palette2.png"><img src="palette2.png" alt="" class="gallery-item"></a>
      <a href="palette3.png"><img src="palette3.png" alt="" class="gallery-item"></a>
      <a href="palette4.png"><img src="palette4.png" alt="" class="gallery-item"></a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".gallery-item").click(function(event) {


  event.preventDefault();
  let overlay = $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");
  let link = $(this).attr("href");

  $("body").append(overlay);
  $("body").append("<img src=" + link + ">");
  });
```

Comment: There is no element with the id `test` in `$("#test").attr("href")`

Comment: Sorry, i used a wrong code snipped. I fixed it

Comment: Before one makes an example for you, did you consider to use some of the free popup solutions? They already have implemented things like blur, close button etc.

Comment: @KvizMajster i want to understand why it doesn't work, not just a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when i try to get the src-attribute it is always "undefined". Can someone explain me how to fix it.

You are attaching the click event to `.gallery-item` and then trying to read it's `href` property - but the gallery items are images and have an `src` property instead.

```js
$(".gallery-item").click(function(event) {


  event.preventDefault();
  let link = $(this).attr("src");

  var $overlay = $("<div id='overlay'></div>");

  $($overlay).append("<img src='" + link + "'>");
  $("body").append($overlay);
});
```

```css
#overlay{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity:0.8;  
}

#overlay img{
  display:block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="palette1.png"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=1" alt="" class="gallery-item"></a>
  <a href="palette2.png"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=2" alt="" class="gallery-item"></a>
  <a href="palette3.png"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=3" alt="" class="gallery-item"></a>
  <a href="palette4.png"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=4" alt="" class="gallery-item"></a>
</div>
```